# How do I change the X-step on the TI-84 Plus?

Tags: calculator

I am trying to create a vertical line in my calculator, but it needs to be restricted to a certain height. I have an equation with a very high slope and I need to restrict its domain to hundredths. I already know how to restrict its domain using logical operators, but the line simply disappears if I lower the domain to a very small amount with the domain still covering the line.

I believe my problem is that the `X-step` of the calculator, the amount of space it has between points, is too low. IIRC the default value is $0.1$, I need to reduce it to $0.001$. I know I've seen this setting before but I can't find it anywhere on the calculator or online.

Comment: https://education.ti.com/en/guidebook/details/en/1743A58846484D5C9C6E1525B2548EED/ti-84-plus-c-silver-edition-guidebook

The manual always helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press "Window". It is not `X-Step`, it is `Xscl`

Comment: No, it's not. All that does is change the amount of points on my axis. It doesn't change how the graph is rendered.

Comment: Aaron, _respect my attempt_. I gave five minutes of my valuable time looking for the answer to this unclear question.  P.S. by unclear, I mean what do you want to find? A way around the points dilemma, or finding the `X-Step`?

Comment: Whichever method works, what matters is that I need to draw shapes and lines using only the Y= menu for a school project.

Comment: My formula that I've come up with so far is `-2(x+7)^2+e^(10x+20)+9/((x<-5 and x>-9) or (x>-1.8 and x<0))` but if I try to restrict the right domain to get a vertical line that doesn't span the screen, it disappears!